# How to compare queryset size with another queryset?

Tags: django

I have three querysets and I want the maximum size among all.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Resources, Journey_template, Topic_Table, Subtopic_Table

def Journey_view(request) :
    if (Journey_template.objects.filter(subtopic_id=1).exists()):
        # obj = Journey_template.objects.filter(subtopic_id=1)
        completed_obj = Journey_template.objects.filter(subtopic_id=1, status='completed')
        pending_obj = Journey_template.objects.filter(subtopic_id=1, status='pending')
        skipped_obj = Journey_template.objects.filter(subtopic_id=1, status='skipped') 
        # print(completed_obj.count(), pending_obj.count(), skipped_obj.count())
        # print(obj.count())
        # return render(request,'journey-page.html',{'data': obj})
    else:
        obj = Resources.objects.filter(topic_id=1,subtopic_id=1)
        # Id = Topic_Table.objects.get(id=topic_id)
        for resource in obj:
            print(resource.resource_id)
            Journey_template(subtopic_id=resource.subtopic_id, resource_id=resource, topic_id=topic_id).save()
    return render(request,'journey-page.html',{'completed' : completed_obj, 'pending' : pending_obj, 'skipped' : skipped_obj})
```

Is there any inbuilt function which returns maximum size.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by size??

Comment: length of queryset.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you're looking for this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#count